# Jquery-ui-slider parameterizing min max and value

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I've a jquery-ui-slider script that transforms all inputs with special class into a slider.

```
// Create Jquery-ui Slider
$(".create_slider").after('<div class="slider"></div>');
//
$(".slider").slider({
    value: $(this).siblings("input").val(),
    min: $(this).siblings("input").data("min"),
    max: $(this).siblings("input").data("max"),
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).siblings("input").val(ui.value);
    }
});
```

Html is:

```
<td>
    <input type="text" value="11" id="jpeg_compression" name="jpeg_compression" data-min="0" data-max="100" class="regular-text create_slider" readonly="">
    <div class="slider"></div>
    <p class="description"></p>
</td>
```

But value-min-max don't work at all. `$(this).siblings("input").data("min")` doesn't work!

I kind of understand why it doesn't work, but what are the solutions?

I fixed value problem by using create:

```
                            //
                            //
                            // Create Jquery-ui Slider
                            $(".create_slider").after('<div class="slider"></div>');
                            //
                            $(".slider").slider({
                              min: $(this).siblings("input").data("min"),
                              max: $(this).siblings("input").data("max"),
                              slide: function(event, ui) {
                                $(this).siblings("input").val(ui.value);
                              },
                              create: function(event, ui){
                                $(this).slider('value',$(this).siblings("input").val());
                              }
                            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from your almost working solution you can use `create` function for the other params too.

You can set `min` and `max` as option with http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#option-max

Code:

```
// Create Jquery-ui Slider
$(".create_slider").after('<div class="slider"></div>');
//
$(".slider").slider({
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).siblings("input").val(ui.value);
    },
    create: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).slider("option", "min", $(this).siblings("input").data("min"));
        $(this).slider("option", "max",  $(this).siblings("input").data("max"));
        $(this).slider('value', $(this).siblings("input").val());
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/HZqA7/

Comment: yep, this is how I did it in the end :)

Answer (score 0):

The `min` and `max` options take numbers, but your `data-` attributes are returned as strings.

You have to convert their values, with [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) for instance:

```
$(".create_slider").after('<div class="slider"></div>');
var $siblings = $(this).siblings("input");
$(".slider").slider({
    value: $siblings.val(),
    min: parseInt($siblings.data("min"), 10),
    max: parseInt($siblings.data("max"), 10),
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        $siblings.val(ui.value);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! But, var $siblings = $(this).siblings("input"); this doesn't work. I also get jquery-ui error when I include parse function.

Comment: @Sandro, I was only doing that to avoid matching the siblings several times. If it does not work, chances are your original code doesn't either. Which error do you receive when you add the calls to `parseInt()`?

Comment: I fixed value problem. But min max remains. I think functions inside slider values simply don't work!

Comment: I get error (quite unrelated): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addClass' of undefined